# Is there a word that means "having to do with genre" or "with respect to genre"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I'm trying to write a paper about artistic genres and adaptation, and it would be many times easier if I knew a word that meant "having to do with genre." I'd thought of using the word "generic," saying things like "generic transformation" to mean "transformation that takes place with regard to genre." But I know that "generic" means "having to do with **genus**," not "having to do with **genre.**" Any chance there's another word I could use? Alternatively, is it actually acceptable to use "generic" in this way?

Thanks!

Comment: You can always coin *genre-wise*. That works in English for pretty much any *with respect to* or *regarding*.

Comment: If you mean having to do with a *particular* genre, you could say a thing is "genre-specific."

Comment: No, I mean "having to do with (the concept of literary) genre."

Comment: Lupicia: If it's important (and it seems to be), I'd make sure 'genric' is listed in OED.

Comment: @Edwin: It's not. But here's at least one writer prepared to use it: [*I use the adjectival form **“genric”** to emphasize the functions of the concept of genre in interpretation. The conventional form **“generic”** has come to connote aspects such as non-specificity and common variety.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+use+the+adjectival+form+genric%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) In context, that's fine by me, since he does actually justify the unusual/non-standard usage, but that's not a ***generic justification*** for using it in any other contexts.

Comment: I see that Harold Bloom has used the word *genric*. https://books.google.com/books?id=FaZP7cR5Z04C&pg=PA196&dq=%22genric%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=X-IvVZTcN9HOsQSyXw&ved=0CFkQ6AEwCg#v=onepage&q=%22genric%22&f=false

Comment: And with that elder-statesman feeling having been thus given the word, it must be okay.

Comment: Are you looking for 'specific to a genre' (without having to say which genre it is) or do you want a word/term for all genres in the abstract (as opposed to non-genre writing)?

Comment: The latter--I mean "having to do with (the concept of literary) genre." As generally as possible.

Comment: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/genre) says that the adjective for *genre* is *genre*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genric), unlike other[,] respectable online dictionaries, lists *genric*, without even a 'rare':

> **genric**
>
> Etymology genre +‎ -ic
>
> Adjective  genric (not comparable)
>
> Pertaining to genre.

But then there's not much Wiktionary doesn't list.

Comment: So it does... but honestly, that looks like a typo for "generic" to me, so I probably wouldn't use it or recommend using it.

Comment: The facts that they list _generic_ separately and offer _cringe_ as an anagram here would not support your view (assuming your 'that' has the obvious referent).

Comment: I think this works: [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=juneBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%22genric%22+definition&source=bl&ots=5t6Kr4NuNJ&sig=C6uZ_TRRi8MBtBVHAFH4Zm8Ca0I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6tovVcecO6aE7gaRkoHQBg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBDgU#v=onepage&q=%22genric%22%20definition&f=false) uses the word "genric" in precisely this way, adding an explanation of the term which you can see if you search the book for "genric."

Comment: I don't mean that I think that was a typo, I said it looks like a typo. A Google search on "genric" gives you the Wiktionary entry on the first page, along with some company that's chosen this name. From the second page on, most of the Google results are misspelled Viagra ads. However, a Google grams search does reveal some legitimate uses of the word in published books, though some of them are false hits for the company name, and one of the first-page hits contains a justification by the author of the choice to use "genric" rather than "generic". It is a word but it seems a bit jargony to me.

Comment: I think in this instance it will be better to be jargony rather than long-winded or inaccurate. If I use even one more than 4400 words, it will hit my grade.

I'll choose a right answer as soon as I can finish registering my account. The confirmation email is taking a long time to show up.

Comment: @Lupica: yes, since you are writing a paper about genres, you don't have to worry too much if you use a specialized term.

Comment: 'Look like' needs disambiguating.

Comment: 'Genric'? Sounds wrong before and after hearing what it is intended for. And it will be jarring even if you define it explicitly.

Comment: @Mitch I'm getting used to it already.

Comment: *Genric* is perfect, and even sounds perfect if you pronounce it correctly!