# Does an adverb for "genre" exist?

Tags: adverbs

I ran into a gap in my diction recently. Does an adverb for *genre* exist? I'm trying to say the following but with adverb form:

> The two songs differed by genre.

However, this doesn't seem quite right:

> The two songs were *genrely* different.

I'm assuming such a word doesn't exist and this is just another downfall of the limited specificity of the English language.

I should add that I want to strictly talk about music when using this unknown word, so anything that doesn't have the root *genre* would defeat the purpose.

Comment: *Genre* is a borrowed word, so it may well be "incomplete". I suspect that the technically-correct word is *typically* (of a type) but that really is a technical use which would not be typical.

Comment: How about *stylistically*? Style and genre are slightly different, but it might work.

Comment: Genre-wise the two songs were different.

Comment: *Categorically*?

Comment: There is no lexical “gap”: that’s why we have phrases for things. Prepositions are there for a purpose.

Comment: Related: Is there a word that means “having to do with genre” or “with respect to genre”?(http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239775/is-there-a-word-that-means-having-to-do-with-genre-or-with-respect-to-genre)

Answer (score 3):

How about **generically**?

generic: relating to or descriptive of an entire group or class ([The American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/generic))

*You can see that, although these songs are  [generically](https://books.google.fr/books?id=SiZtBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT241&lpg=PT241&dq=%22songs+are+generically%22&source=bl&ots=8d6BJi9c2O&sig=bjPzWVzz2vwpJy_X-zJXVtgKLgk&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAWoVChMIjOSKioOwyAIVBVQUCh3q5gR4#v=onepage&q=%22songs%20are%20generically%22&f=false) very different..., they all share one thing in common...*

Comment: I cannot speak for MuCrit, but this is certainly the term used in LitCrit: *genre* → *generic* → *generically*.

Answer (score 0):

If you say *musical style* it would be clear to most people that you are referring to the "genre", even if it's not 100% the same thing.

"The two songs differed by musical style"

Similarly, you could say *musical classification* or *category* and that may even be more clear although it's a bit longer.